# objective-C, sort an array of strings containing numbers

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nssortdescriptor

Lets suppose I have an array like this

```
NSArray* arr = @[@"1",@"4",@"2",@"8",@"11",@"10",@"14",@"9"]; //note: strings containing numbers
```

and I want to sort them like this: [1,2,4,8,9,10,11,14]

but if I use

```
[arr sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

I get [1,10,11,14,2,4,8,9]... and if I use:

```
   NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"length" ascending:YES];
   NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];
   [arr sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

I get something like this: [1,4,2,8,9,11,10,14]

How can I combine both predicates? or is any other easier way to solve this? note: The output of this array is merely for debug purposes, I dont care if the result turns the array into integers as long as I can print in console with NSLog thanks

Comment: actually it would be better a function that returns the numbers missing between the min and the max value... example input: [1,5,4]... output:[2,3]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try using blocks

```
[arr sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {

    if ([obj1 intValue] == [obj2 intValue])
        return NSOrderedSame;

    else if ([obj1 intValue] < [obj2 intValue])
        return NSOrderedAscending;

    else
        return NSOrderedDescending;

}];
```

Comment: thanks pal, I just had to change the ">" for "<"

Comment: oh sorry my bad. I updated the answer.

Comment: The important part of this answer is lost in the minimal explanation. You can sort using blocks or sort descriptors -- it's not *blocks* that make the difference here. The important thing is to use `-intValue` rather than trying to combine `-length` and `-localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:`.

Answer (score 13):

The problem is that you're trying to use both string comparison and `-length` to cobble together what you really want, which is numeric comparison. But sort descriptors are applied one at a time, and a second descriptor is only used if the first one orders two items as the same. Using `-intValue` to order the items lets you use a single sort descriptor that will order the items the way you want.

Do this instead:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"intValue" ascending:YES];
[arr sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
```